# Does the virtual filesystem work on top of character devices and network subsystems?

Tags: linux, network-interface, vfs, character-device, virtual-file-system

Does the virtual filesystem work on top of character devices and network subsystems, or just on top of filesystems and block devices?

Could you also explain a bit about in what sense "the VFS is working on top of" something mean?

Thanks.

A figure from [Linux Device Driver](https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/) seems to say no.

[image]

A figure from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devpts) seems to say yes:

[image]

Comment: presumably the color-coding in the wikipedia picture means something?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: Wikipedia means all those strange type of files can be accessed through VFS, not just normal block-device filesystems

Comment: @神秘德里克 what does LDD mean?

Comment: It means kernel expose interface that let you access all those things

Answer (score 1):

A virtual filesystem that is based on modern mmap technologies works as a intermediate layer between the foreground memory and the background memory.

On SunOS (this is where the concept is from) there is a generic layer called `segvn` which is the generic vnode segement driver and a VFS implementation uses segvn to get callbacks from memory faults (typically missing data from the background memory). The background memory used by local filesystems is typically a block device driver, but a VFS may implement anything appropriate, e.g. calling network IO.

So what a VFS implementation actually does is to implement a store method for data that manages to link a data element in the filesystem namespace to e.g. a block on a background storage device.